# Not able to get SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK working in combination with StyledText and TextStyle

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am very new to using `StyledText`, `TextStyle`.

I am trying to give a hyperlink look for a text that is displayed. I am using `TextStyle` object to create a hyper link style text. For `TextStyle` constructor I am passing `Font` object which has the style `SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK`, expecting it to create a text with hyperlink style [as per javadoc].

I am not able get this style working. Other styles `SWT.BOLD`, `SWT.ITALICS` works but not `SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK`. Are there any special conditions to use `SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK`?

Answer (score 2):

Check this Thread-
[Can HTML-Style Links be added to SWT StyledText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494337/can-html-style-links-be-added-to-swt-styledtext)

and 
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/swt/create-link.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
styleRange.underline = true;
```

when using the underlineStyle

```
styleRange.underlineStyle = SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK;
```